# Androic C#: Using two different layout in the ViewPager

Tags: c#, android

I want to implement a viewpager to my app. The first and second screen will look like this: [image]

So basically I want the user to either swipe left or swipe right and then always get the screen that is not visible. As you can see, only the center part changes at all. That means I need two different table layouts that are designed specifically for either position 1 and / or position 2. 
Ive seen many tutorials on how to implement a view pager, but not on how to have two completely unique designs shown. Can anyone give me a hint on where to do that? That would be awesome!! THANKS

*** THE CODE:

Okay, so the first thing I do in my mainactivity is initilazie the pageviewer:

```
private void initViewPager()
{
    ViewPager _viewpager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
    _viewpager.Adapter = new FragmentAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
}
```

Then, I have two more classes in my mainactivity:

```
  public class FragmentAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public FragmentAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        { 

        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return 2; }
        }

        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return new LayoutFragment();
        }
    }


    public class LayoutFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Viewpage1, container, false);    

            return view; 
        }
    }
```

Now, As you can see - I am inflating a Layout called "ViewPage1". In this, I designed the first of the two mid parts and it works. I set the count to "2" and now I am getting the same layout twice. Ofcourse I need an "IF" to check wether I am on position one or two to load another XML layout. Thanks for helping me with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the center portion of the screen to change then I would suggest you to implement it by only changing the center fragment on the swipe. You should change the images and their corresponding text in the layout files of the different views.

Comment: Right, so what I did so far is I put a ViewPager inside a LinearLayout that covers only the center portion. But what I dont know, Do i need like two different XMLs for both screens or how does that work?

Comment: Yes I think that would be the solution for it. You will have to inflate the appropriate xml corresponding to the swipe of the user.

Comment: Alright. Thats what I thought. So - could I show you my code and you would tell me where exactly to inflate what layout? that be awesome :)

Comment: AWESOME! Just did :) The viewpager it self is working but only with the same layout twice. Where would I put my "if"? THANKS!

Comment: I want to see how have you implemented the fragment. I mean inflating the layout on swipe will be heavy task and would create  same view twice rather than there is a scope of reusing the existing views. Also you will have to handle the logic for the two different layouts in the same java file which would become a bit difficult for you to code and understand as well. Also this can lead to some errors too.

Comment: Sorry, what exaclty do you mean? The code of the whole mainactivity?

Comment: I mean, cant I just have the two layouts (which I have now) And then load layout1 for page1 or the Viewpager and Layout2 for Page 2 of the Viewpager? They do not need to be dynamic or anything :)

Comment: They should be dynamic to improve performance as well as to reduce overhead code and the chances or error would be much less.

Comment: I would suggest to change the views dynamically instead of changing the layout.

Comment: okay thnanks a lot i found it out ( switch statement in within the getitem) switching the position!

Comment: Great glad it helped.